# ObservableCollection Asynchronous Items Not Adding

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I currently have an ObservableCollection:

```
private readonly object _outputCollectionLock = new object();
private ObservableCollection<ChatterOutput> _outputs;
public ObservableCollection<ChatterOutput> Outputs
{
    get { return _outputs; }
    set 
    { 
        _outputs = value; 
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_outputs, _outputCollectionLock); 
    }
}
```

The issue is arising with one of my event handlers. When the event handler is dispatched I am adding a new object like so:

```
lock (_outputCollectionLock)
{
    Outputs.Add(new ChatterOutput{Option = option});
}
```

In any breakpoints I set after the lock, I can see new items being added to the collection. However, if I breakpoint at a different time, I see no new elements have been added.

I have tried invoking it on the `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, but this did not change anything. The only other thing that is using these collections is an XAML binding, which is `Mode=OneWay`.

Is this a threading issue, or am I missing something altogether?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us how you tried using dispatcher? And one more thing for `ObservableCollection`, you can't use it with `CollectionViewSource` in XAML.

Comment: wrap that Add call in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call.

Comment: First of all remove `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_outputs, _outputCollectionLock);` and shift it to the constructor of your `ViewModel`. And I tried your code using Task and it worked nicely.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here came from passing elements to multiple classes.
As I passed the Outputs from one class to another, and then used threaded event handlers, the classes became separate and therefore modifying the Collection was not modifying the correct one.

In order to resolve this, find a work around for passing classes in the constructor, if you're going to multi thread it. My solution was a Singleton pattern.

Thank you to everyone in the comments.